# Return outside of function

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a blackjack card game simulator, but I keep getting a 'return outside of function on this part of my code, ill post the entire code at the bottom, but at the top is where I'm getting the first error to pop up. I'm newish to python so it might be something small, but cant seems to figure it out.

```
for i in deck_copy:
    if i[0]==suit:
        deck.remove((suit,i[1]))
        return sorted(deck)


a=551
seed(a)



def create_standard_deck():
    deck = list(product(suits,numbers))
    return sorted(deck)




def get_all_cards(deck):
    return sorted([i for i in deck])




def get_all_twos(deck):
    return sorted([i for i in deck if i[1]==2])




def get_all_aces(deck):
    return sorted([i for i in deck if i[1]==14])




def get_card_number(deck,card_number):
    return sorted([i for i in deck if i[1]==card_number])




def get_card_suit(deck,suit):
    return sorted([i for i in deck if i[0]==suit])




def get_number_and_suit(deck,num,suit):
    return sorted([i for i in deck if i[0]==suit and i[1]==num])




def remove_card_from_deck(deck,suit,num):
    deck.remove((suit,num))
    return get_all_cards(deck)




def remove_suit_from_deck(deck,suit):
    deck_copy = list(deck)




for i in deck_copy:
    if i[0]==suit:
        deck.remove((suit,i[1]))
        return sorted(deck)




def remove_number_from_deck(deck,number):
    deck_copy = list(deck)





for i in deck_copy:
    if i[0]==number:
        deck.remove((i[1],number))
        pass
        return sorted(deck)




def add_card_to_deck(deck,suit,num):
    if suit in suits and num in numbers:
        deck.append((suit,num))
        return sorted(deck)




def add_suit_to_deck(deck,suit):
    if suit in suits:
        additional_cards=list(product(suit,numbers))
        deck.extend(additional_cards)
        return sorted(deck)




def add_number_to_deck(deck,number):
    if number in numbers:
        additional_cards=list(product(suits,number))
        deck.extend(additional_cards)
        return sorted(deck)




def draw_card(deck):
    card=choice(deck)
    remove_card_from_deck(deck,*card)
    return card




def display_dealer(opponent,start=False):
    print('Dealer:')
    if start:
        the_output=[opponent[0],('?''?')]
        print(the_output)
    else:
        print(opponent)




def display_player(player):
    print('Player')
    print(player)





def get_count(player):
    count = 0
    for cards in player:
        if cards[1]==14:
            count+=11
        elif cards[1]>=10:
            count+=10
        else:
            count+=cards[1]
            return count







def check_cards(player):
    count=get_count(player)
    if count==21:
        return 'WIN'
    elif count>21:
        return 'BUST'
    else:
        return 'OK'





def create_blackjack_game(user_input):
    opponent=[]
    player=[]
    deck=create_standard_deck()
    opponent.append(draw_card(deck))
    opponent.append(draw_card(deck))
    player.append(draw_card(deck))
    player.append(draw_card(deck))
    player_count=get_count(player)
    dealer_count=get_count(opponent)
    display_dealer(opponent,start=True)
    display_player(player)



if not user_input:
    player_action=input('press h to hit,s to stand,q to quit.').lower().strip(linesep)
    while player_action not in ('s','h','q'):
        player_action=input('press h to hit,s to stand,q to quit.').lower().strip(linesep)
    else:
            player_action=user_input.pop(0)




if player_action=='q':
    pass
    return 0
    while player_action!='q':
        if player_action=='h':
            player.append(draw_card(deck))
            display_dealer(opponent,start=True)
            display_player(player)
            player_result=check_cards(player)
            player_count=get_count(player)
        if player_result=='WIN':
            print('You Win!')
            pass
            return 1
        elif player_result=='BUST':
            print('You Bust,dealer wins.')
            pass
            return -1
        else:
            while get_count(opponent)<17:
                print('Dealer Hits!')
                opponent.append(draw_card(deck))
                display_dealer(opponent)
                display_player(player)
                dealer_result=check_cards(opponent)
                dealer_count=get_count(opponent)
        if dealer_result=='WIN':
            Print('Dealer Wins')
            return -1
        elif dealer_result=='BUST':
            print('Dealer Busts,you win.')
            return 1




print('player:{},Dealer:{}'.format(player_count,dealer_count))




if player_count>dealer_count:
    print('You Win!')
 

   return 1
else:
    print('Dealer Wins')
    return-1




if not user_input:
    player_action=input('h to hit,s to stand,q to quit.').lower().strip(linesep)
    while player_action not in ('s','h','q'):
        player_action=input('press h to hit,s to stand,q to quit.').lower().strip(linesep)
        if player_action=='q':
            return 0
        else:
            player_action = user_input.pop(0)
        if __name__== " __main__":
            pass


create_blackjack_game(None)
```

Comment: one of your for loops is outdented to the same level as a def of a function.  that means its not part of the function and the return in that loop is likely throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so forgive this answer. I'll try and update this if you give more information.

Firstly that cannot be all your code. The `seed()` function isn't declared/imported.

Is there lines like the ones below somewhere?

```py
from numpy import product
from random import seed
```

Generally, in terms of your error, you can't return outside of a function.
For example, this causes an error:

```py
if a==1:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

But this will work.

```py
def function_name(a):
    if a==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# To display the result call on the function
x = 3 # let x = 3
print(function_name(x)) # this will print 0 to the console
```

If you only want to see the result you could replace returns with print in the earlier example, and it will no longer result in an error.

```py
if a==1:
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: from itertools import product
from random import choice, seed
from os import linesep

suits={'hearts','clubs','spades','diamonds'}
numbers=set([i for i in range(2,15)])

Comment: Thats the code that i had left out. My fault.